# How to do animations on change of media queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, zurb-foundation, css-animations

I'm using foundation 5 for a project, and I simply can't find any article on how tyo do nice animation on the change of media queries (e.g. if you resize the window, and the layout change, the site nicely reflows)
see example here, some guys do it:

http://www.andremaurice.it/it/lookbook-woman

if you resize this page to an ipad portrait size, you can see the blocks really nicely reflow to their new position. Any ideas how I should do this on a site built with foundation 5?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

well finally found the answer myself

```
.columns{-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease 0s; -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;-ms-transition: all 0.8s ease 0s; transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;}
```